# Different Paypal accounts depending on product

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm currently testing Woocommerce on my Wordpress site, and I'd like to know if it is possible to have two Paypal accounts linked to your shop. The idea would be to dedicate one account for a type of product and the other one for another type.

I've tried to look into the extensions available, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Paypal, you can use Paypal Adaptive payments.

You can link each products to a Vendor as a marketplace website will do. ie : for woocommerce WC-Vendors, Dokkan...

Depending on which e-commerce plugin you have embed into your website, you can create a dedicated payment gateway that will switch the producct owner email, but this will a time wasting and maybe a untrustly method.

Hope it helps